# Why are the hypotheses of L'Hôpital's Theorem not satisfied here?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Hi i was wondering if anyone can help me with the following problem

[image]

Specifically 4 i was just wondering why they are not satisfied since both the numerator and denominator are differentiable

For 5 what does it mean by carefully evaluating the limit? and how would we do this for a function like f, since it's piecewise?

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is not differentiable anywhere it is defined. (Note that in particular it's not differentiable in an open neighbourhood of $0$; L'Hôpital's rule requires differentiability near the limit point.)

To evaluate the limit, you can divide top and bottom by $x$ and use that the limit of a quotient (where the denominator is nonzero) is the quotient of the limits (where the denominator has nonzero limit). By "carefully" it means "prove every step you use, or if you don't prove a step, state it carefully and state why it is valid".

A careless proof of your problem might start "By l'Hôpital's rule…". This is careless because the hypotheses of l'Hôpital's rule don't hold, so your argument is not strictly speaking valid.

Comment: may i ask why is it not defined at 0?

Comment: Because then the denominator is zero (by "it" I assume you mean the fraction)

Comment: but if we use hopitals we differentiate the bottom and the top don't we?

Comment: But here you can't use the rule, as indicated by Patrick.

Comment: Why should l’Hôpital’s rule require the function to be defined at the point where the limit is computed at? It doesn't. It requires differentiability in a (right, in this case) punctured neighborhood of the point.

Comment: "L'Hôpital's rule requires the limit point to be inside the interval of definition of the function." As @egreg said, this is not true -  at all. Please edit.

Comment: okay i'm really confused now.

Comment: @Gibberish By what are you confused? The first step to enlightenment is being extremely specific.

Comment: because of the comments @PatrickStevens

Comment: This may be something which has caused you to become confused, but it is not your confusion. Describe your confusion.

Comment: (+1) but if we're nitpicking, $f$ _is_ differentiable at $0$, and $f'(0) = 0$; it's just that $f$ isn't differentiable anywhere else. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Fixed :)

Comment: okay so if we time through by x do we use hopitals on that then? because it would also be 0?

Comment: @Gibberish If you divide top and bottom by $x$, you get something you can just evaluate, without L'Hôpital.

Comment: i calculated the value of the limit to be $\frac{0}{1}=0$ is this correct?

Comment: The limit is $0$, but the point of the question is to evaluate it *carefully* rather than just stating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the idea that f(x), $x^2$ for x rational, 0 for x irrational, was differentiable?  It is not even continuous except at x= 0.

Comment: I think this is a comment, not an answer.